# Facebook Account Verification, without the approval via facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

We currently use a social network login/signup system.
The user would click login/signup and it would use the facebook account to allow access.

Other sites that do this e.g. [9gag](http://www.9gag.com) and so on.

Currently the user will go to our site, click signup, then get pushed to facebook, approve it, and then the data is passed to our site/MySQL, creating the session in php and allowing content access.

[9gag](http://www.9gag.com) uses the same system, but misses the need to go to facebook and click the approve button. It just signs them up regardless of the facebook fallback.

Does anyone know how you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry friend, but I guess you're mistaken. I tried to do what you said at 9GAG and I got this:
**9GAG would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address. (OK) (CANCEL)**